# PHP TAKE data from sqlite database from android app and put them in data base on server

Tags: php, android, sql

```
    public function storeLog($uuid, $log) {
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO logs(unique_id, thelog) VALUES('$uuid', '$log')");
    $json = json_decode($log);

    foreach($json as $item) {
        $type = $item->type;
        if($type == "out_sms") {
            $number = $item->number;
            //$time = $item->time;
            //$time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $time);
            //jebna kel shi la hay el sms
            $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO sms(UUID, TYPE, NUMBER) VALUES('$uuid', '$type', '$number')");
        }
            else if($type == "in_sms") {
            $number = $item->number;
            //$time = $item->time;
            //$time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $time);
            //jebna kel shi la hay el sms
            $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO sms(UUID, TYPE, NUMBER) VALUES('$uuid', '$type', '$number')");
        }
            else if($type == "in_call") {
            $number = $item->number;
            $time_answered = $item->time_answered;
    $time_ended = $item->time_ended;
            $time_ended = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $time_ended);
    $time_started = $item->time_started;
           $time_started = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $time_started);
           $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO call(UUID, TYPE, NUMBER, TIME_ANSWERED, TIME_ENDED, TIME_STARTED) VALUES('$uuid', '$type', '$number','$time_amswered', `$time_ended`, `$time_started`)");
       }
            else if($type == "out_call") {
            $number = $item->number;
            $time_ended = $item->time_ended;
            //$time_ended = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $time_ended);
            $time_started = $item->time_started;
            //$time_started = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $time_started); 
            $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO call(UUID, TYPE, NUMBER, TIME_ENDED, TIME_STARTED) VALUES('$uuid', '$type', '$number', `$time_ended`, `$time_started`)");
        }
            else if($type == "data") {
            $mobile_sent = $item->mobile_sent;
            //$time = $item->time;
            $network_received = $item->network_received;
            $network_sent = $item->network_sent;
            $mobile_received = $item->mobile_received;
            $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO data(UUID, TYPE, MOBILE_SENT, NETWORK_RECEIVED, NETWORK_SENT, MOBILE_RECEIVED) VALUES('$uuid', '$type', '$mobile_sent', '$network_received', '$network_sent', '$mobile_received')");
```

I am new to php language and working in my university final project.
The problem is every function work fine except the two in_call and out_call it doesn't work any help please.

Comment: Also the time it come integer from android database and it cant take it in the php and stored in database on server?

Answer (score 0):

you can create a php file which inserts and communicates with the server. Then your app will just call this php file and that's it!. Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thats what i do but the else if loop for type in_call and out_call not working and the other loop work correct